# I want to print the player's case value in my Deal or No Deal game

Tags: python-3.9

I am coding a deal or no deal game using python. I ran the game several times and fixed some of the bugs already. Currently, I am fixing this problem that the code keeps on printing the remaining values instead of the value of the player's briefcase at the end of the game.

This is the code:

```
import random

def play_game():
    # Set up the game
    briefcases = [0.01, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 750,
                 1000, 5000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 75000, 100000,
                 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 750000, 1000000]
    random.shuffle(briefcases)

    # Function to check if input is valid
    def is_valid(case):
        if not case.isdigit():
            return False
        case = int(case)
        if case < 1 or case > 26:
            return False
        if briefcases[case-1] == "X":
            return False
        if case-1 == player_case:
            return False
        return True

    # Select a briefcase
    player_case = input("Choose a briefcase (1-26): ")
    while not is_valid(player_case):
        print("Invalid input. Please choose a number between 1 and 26 that has not been opened.")
        player_case = input("Choose a briefcase (1-26): ")
    player_case = int(player_case) -1
    player_value = briefcases[player_case]

    # Function to display briefcases in two columns
    def display_briefcases(briefcases):
        display_briefcases = list(briefcases)
        display_briefcases[player_case] = "Player"
        sorted_values = sorted([x for x in display_briefcases if isinstance(x, int)])
        half = len(sorted_values) //2
        for i in range(half):
            print("{:<10}{:<10}".format(sorted_values[i], sorted_values[i+half]))
        if len(sorted_values) %2 ==1:
            print("{:<10}".format(sorted_values[-1]))

    # Function to display remaining cases in two columns
    def display_remaining_cases(briefcases):
        remaining_cases = [i+1 for i in range(26) if briefcases[i] != "X"]
        half = len(remaining_cases) //2
        for i in range(half):
            print("{:<10}{:<10}".format(remaining_cases[i], remaining_cases[i+half]))
        if len(remaining_cases) %2 ==1:
            print("{:<10}".format(remaining_cases[-1]))

    # Play the game
    rounds = [6]
    for r in rounds:
        print("Player's briefcase:", player_case +1)
        print("Remaining Cases:")
        display_remaining_cases(briefcases)
        print("Remaining Values:")
        display_briefcases(briefcases)
        for i in range(r):
            case = input("Choose a briefcase to open: ")
            while not is_valid(case):
                print("Invalid input. Please choose a number between 1 and 26 that has not been opened and is not your own briefcase.")
                case = input("Choose a briefcase to open: ")
            case = int(case) -1
            value = briefcases[case]
            print("Briefcase", case +1 , "contains", value)
            briefcases[case] = "X"
        total = sum([x for x in briefcases if x != "X"])
        cases_left = len([x for x in briefcases if x != "X"])
        offer = round(total / cases_left,2)
        print("Banker's offer:", offer)
        deal = input("Deal or No Deal? (D/N): ").upper()
        while deal not in ["D", "N"]:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter 'D' for Deal or 'N' for No Deal.")
            deal = input("Deal or No Deal? (D/N): ").upper()
        if deal == "D":
            break

    # Final round
    if deal != "D":
        while len([x for x in briefcases if x != "X"]) >2:
            print("Player's briefcase:", player_case +1)
            print("Remaining Cases:")
            display_remaining_cases(briefcases)
            print("Remaining Values:")
            display_briefcases(briefcases)
            case = input("Choose a briefcase to open: ")
            while not is_valid(case):
                print("Invalid input. Please choose a number between 1 and 26 that has not been opened and is not your own briefcase.")
                case = input("Choose a briefcase to open: ")
            case = int(case) -1
            value = briefcases[case]
            print("Briefcase", case +1 , "contains", value)
            briefcases[case] = "X"
            total = sum([x for x in briefcases if x != "X"])
            cases_left = len([x for x in briefcases if x != "X"])
            offer = round(total / cases_left,2)
            print("Banker's offer:", offer)
            deal = input("Deal or No Deal? (D/N): ").upper()
            while deal not in ["D", "N"]:
                print("Invalid input. Please enter 'D' for Deal or 'N' for No Deal.")
                deal = input("Deal or No Deal? (D/N): ").upper()
            if deal == "D":
                break
        if deal != "D":
            print("Player's briefcase:", player_case +1)
            print("Remaining Cases:")
            display_remaining_cases(briefcases)
            print("Remaining Values:")
            display_briefcases(briefcases)
            total = sum([x for x in briefcases if x != "X"])
            cases_left = len([x for x in briefcases if x != "X"])
            offer = round(total / cases_left,2)
            print("Banker's final offer:", offer)
            deal = input("Deal or No Deal? (D/N): ").upper()
            while deal not in ["D", "N"]:
                print("Invalid input. Please enter 'D' for Deal or 'N' for No Deal.")
                deal = input("Deal or No Deal? (D/N): ").upper()
    if deal == "D":
        print("You won", offer)
    else:
        print("Your briefcase contains", player_value)
    briefcases[player_case] = player_value
    print("Final Values:")
    display_briefcases(briefcases)

# Start the game
play_again = "Y"
while play_again == "Y":
    play_game()
    play_again = input("Do you want to play again? (Y/N): ").upper()
    while play_again not in ["Y", "N"]:
        print("Invalid input. Please enter 'Y' to play again or 'N' to quit.")
        play_again = input("Do you want to play again? (Y/N): ").upper()
```

This code prints remaining values after selecting deal instead of printing the player's case value.

I want the result to look like this

`You won *banker's offer* Your briefcase contains *case value*`

your help would be much appreciated thank you